# IOS development Certificate expiring and the limit of creating a new has been crossed

Tags: ios

The IOS development certificate has expired and when I try to create a new certificate it shows that the limit is crossed and I can't seem to find a solution for the same. I tried deleting the expired IOS development certificate but getting the same error.

Also, does the already uploaded apps in the App Store get affected or stops working if the IOS development certificate is expired?

Comment: no, its not affected to uploaded apps. it's affected when your apps have push notification and push certificate expired. after push certificate expired, push will not work but app works.

Comment: If you have reached the limit you will need to revoke one of your existing certificates before you can create a new one.  Revoking a certificate will not affect released apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have reached the maximum limit of creating certificates, you need to revoke existing certificates. And it will not affect the existing apps on App Store.